# Is there a tool to check cache and its status in nextjs?

Tags: next.js, caching, fetch

I use nextjs and server component in this project first time.

I use React-Query in vite react project before.
React-Query provides the devtool to check cache. I'm satisfied with its ui.

I feel nextjs makes using cache easier to expand fetch api.
Is there a wonderful tool in nextjs?